# What is the new IMAGE_DEPENDS_wic_append_suffix notation?

Tags: bitbake, openembedded

Previously this was acceptable and easily understood:

```
IMAGE_DEPENDS_wic_append_armada38x = " virtual/bootloader"
```

since this patch https://patchwork.openembedded.org/patch/143213/ 
the assigned value would become either

```
 "virtual/bootloader:do_populate_sysroot"
```

or

```
 "virtual/bootloader-native:do_populate_sysroot"
```

but because we were assigning to an `_append_override` form, it's not clear how this should appear.

Would this work?

```
do_image_wic_armada38x[depends] += "virtual/bootloader:do_populate_sysroot"
```

as an override += it seems that the whole overridden flag would override the normal original one instead of appending to it; I mean that `do_image_wic_armada38x[depends]` would accumulate values and then have the `armada38x` suffix stripped; and would the entire variable override or just the flags?

A safer way seems to be the two stage:

```
OLD_IMAGE_DEPENDS_wic_append_armada38x += "virtual/bootloader:do_populate_sysroot"
do_image_wic[depends] += "${OLD_IMAGE_DEPENDS_wic}"
```